# How to count time on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<h1>TIME: <%= Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S") %></h1>
```

In the template, my time is stopped. I want to animate it time like a digital watch.

The time is changed when I refresh a page.

For example, I'm going to index page and now the time shows: 12:30:50 (HH:MM:SS). I refresh again and the time shows: 12:31:10.

I want to show my seconds like this: 50 51 52 53 54.....

Comment: i think much better to do it with javascript or jquery

Comment: Rails generates the html then delivers it to the browser. After that, rails doesn't have anything to do with it. In order to have something dynamically changing on the page, you need a client-side script - eg javascript. You can write javascript into rails templates and rails will pass it to the browser to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function displayTime() {
    var timer=document.getElementById('timer');
    var currentdate = new Date(); 
    var hours = currentdate.getHours();
    var minutes = currentdate.getMinutes();
    var seconds = currentdate.getSeconds();
    timer.innerHTML = hours + ':' + ("0" + minutes).slice(-2) + ':' +  ("0" + seconds).slice(-2);    
};

setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
```

```html
<h1>Time : 
    <p id="timer">
        <%= Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S") %>
    </p>
</h1>
```

First, let's create a function that displays the current date. For this, we just have to find the `p` tag we are interested in (using `getElementById`), and put use `innerHTML` to write in it. That's the function `displayTime`.

Then, we want to run this function every second, so we use : `setInterval`.

Note I keep `<%= Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S") %>` so that if javascript is not enabled there is still a date. If that's not the intended behavior then you can replace it.

Comment: Converted your code to runnable form. The ERB part doesn't quite work, of course.